# Initializing a property delegate in a subclass

Tags: swift

I'm trying to figure out the correct order of operations for my subclass.  I have a subclass that has a dataCollector property that conforms to DataCollectorProtocol. I need to set MySubclass as the delegate when I initialize the DataCollector as seen in the constructor.  This works fine, but I had to declare dataCollector as `DataCollectorProtocol!` with the `!`.  If I tried without it, then I cannot call super.init first because the dataCollector property is not initialized yet.

If I switch the two and call super.init after setting dataCollector, I cannot either since in `(delegate: self)`, self is not initialized.  Is the way I have it laid out by using `!` the proper approach or is there a better more idiomatic Swift way?

```
class MySubclass: BaseClass {

    var dataCollector: DataCollectorProtocol!

    required public init(delegate: SomeOtherDelegate) {
        super.init(delegate: delegate)

        dataCollector = DataCollector(delegate: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to set the delegate of `DataCollector` after you have created the object?  In that case I would instantiate `DataCollector` in the declaration of `dataCollector`, then set the delegate after the call to `super.init`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reread your question and figured out what you were *really* trying to do (my original answer is in the edit).

Try this:

```
class MySubclass: BaseClass, DataCollectorProtocol {

    var dataCollector : DataCollector?

    required public init(delegate: SomeOtherDelegate) {
        super.init(delegate: delegate)

        dataCollector = DataCollector(delegate: self)
    }
}
```

And when you need to call any methods on `dataCollector`, don't forget to dereference:

```
 self.dataCollector?.someFineMethodToBeCalled()
```

Comment: This is probably the safest answer.  If you still want to use an implicit unwrap, I would suggest making it `private (set)`.